# How can I change menu toggle state when route changed with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, menu, toggle

I want to change the menu state when route changed but can't make it work.

The problem that I'm facing: when I click on a link from the navbar. The route changes but It won't close. How do I change menu state when route changed? Can react-router-redux help me with this?

ACTION

```
export function menuToggle(currentState) {
  return {
    type: 'MENU_TOGGLE',
    payload: {
      ToggleMenu: !currentState,
    },
  };
}
```

REDUCER

```
const initialState = {
  showMenu: false,
};

export const MenuToggle = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case MENU_TOGGLE:
      return {
        showMenu: action.payload.ToggleMenu,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

COMPONENT

```
class Header extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClickOutside, false);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClickOutside, false);
  }

  handleClickOutside = e => {
    if (!ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).contains(e.target)) {
      this.props.showMenu === true && this.props.menuToggle(!false);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Head>
        <Brand>BRAND</Brand>
        <MenuButton
          onClick={this.props.menuToggle.bind(null, this.props.showMenu)}
        >
          MENU
        </MenuButton>
        <MobileMenu showMenu={this.props.showMenu} />
      </Head>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    showMenu: state.MenuToggle.showMenu,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = { menuToggle };

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(Header);
```

CHILD COMPONENT

```
const MobileMenu = ({ showMenu }) => {
  return (
    showMenu === true && (
      <Nav>
        <Ul>
          <Li>
            <A to="/">
              <Span>Home</Span>
            </A>
          </Li>
          <Li>
            <A to="/shop">
              <Span>Shop</Span>
            </A>
          </Li>
          <Li>
            <A to="/contact">
              <Span>Contact</Span>
            </A>
          </Li>
        </Ul>
      </Nav>
    )
  );
};

export default MobileMenu;
```

Comment: Can you check if the value you are gettng on mapStateToProps is correct?

Comment: Yes its working good.

Answer (score 0):

Yes react-router-redux can help you.
You can listen LOCATION_CHANGE in your reducer and turn off "showMenu".